# Timestamps in JSON file

Tags: python, json, pandas, timestamp

I have a JSON file with time stamps that look like the following:

```
2012-03-01T00:05:55+00:00
```

I am not very familiar with JSON files and am looking for some thoughts on how to convert this to a more digestible format for analysis.

I am using pandas at the moment to upload the JSON so any rec's for python would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Those are just ISO8601-formatted strings. JSON has no timestamp format. You can parse those into `datetime` objects, see [How to parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

The Pandas [`read_json()` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) handles that format natively, as long as you keep the `convert_dates` flag set to True or to a list of column names to treat as dates:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> sample = '{"0": {"event":true, "title": "Lorum Ipsum", "date": "2012-03-01T00:05:55+00:00"}}'
>>> pd.read_json(StringIO(sample), orient='index')
                 date  event        title
0 2012-03-01 00:05:55      1  Lorum Ipsum
>>> _.date
0   2012-03-01 00:05:55
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The `date` column was automatically detected here because the column name indicated it was a date.